# scala return type mismatch of function

Tags: scala, io

I'm just dipping my feet into scala and am stuck on why this method does not compile. I want header to find a file given a directory path and a text file name and return the first n lines of the text file. The compile error I get is:

> type mismatch;
>
> found: Unit
>
> required:String

```
import java.io._
def header(fileName:String, directory:String =".",n:Int=5): String = {
  val files = new File(directory).listFiles
  for (file <- files if file.getName == fileName)  {

    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(file)

    try{
      val string=source.getLines.toList.slice(0,n).mkString
      string
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception => "not good. something went wrong"
    }
    finally{
      source.close
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is not returning the response as you expect. Either you can use mutable variable there and return the variable. (not recommended)

```
    {
      ...

      var response = ""
      for (file <- files if file.getName == fileName)  {
            try {
              response = source.getLines.toList.slice(0,n).mkString
            }
            ...
      } // end of for
      response
    }
```

Or use `.filter` followed by `.map` which gives you an `Array[String]`.

```
def header(fileName:String, directory:String =".",n:Int=5): String = {

  val files = new File(directory).listFiles

  val response= files.filter(_.getName.equals(fileName)).map {  file =>
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(file)
    val sliced = source.getLines.toList.slice(0,n).mkString
    source.close()
    sliced
  }

  response(0)
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get more and more functional programming patterns into my code in learning scala so the second filter/map method is pretty slick.

Comment: definitely, don't use first answer as thats how you'd do in non-functional languages.

Comment: However what about closing each of the sources at the end? I tried adding a source.close to the function literal in the map method but it gave me a type error again.

Comment: I updated answer to do that, you will have to store the result in some variable and return after closing source